# What is the keyboard shortcut for CTRL + CLICK in Visual Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

What is the shortcut key to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+Click (Follow Link) in Visual Code? If it doesn't have one, is there any way to add it?

[image]

In Eclipse, if I press <kbd>F3</kbd> I can open the file, like Ctrl+Click

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In HTML files the command is *"Open Link"* (`editor.action.openLink`). This command does not have, by default, associated a key combination. You can assign one by using the **Preferences** -> **Keyboard Shortcuts** command from the menu (click on the gear on the bottom of the primary side bar).

In other contexts (source code in various programming languages), the combination Ctrl+click (or Cmd+click on macOS) when the cursor is on an identifier (constant name, variable name, function name, class name, etc.) is equivalent with command *"Go to Definition"* (`editor.action.revealDefinition`). This command has, by default, associated the key `F12`.

Comment: Is the a way to do so for classes and functions?

Comment: What do you recommend using for this? There's so many keybindings by default, it's as if there's barely any decent options left. I think this should be a default binding.

Comment: @moghwan I think this is `editor.action.revealDefinition`, mine was set to `F12` by default.

Answer (score 3):

Do Command/Control P > keybindings.json and insert:

```
[
    ...,
    {
        "key": "ctrl+f12",
        "command": "editor.action.openLink"
    }
]
```

to set Ctrl F12 to open the link under the cursor.