# How to open a Class or function with keyboard shortcut in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

How can I simulate <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd> with keyboard to open a corresponding class, function or a file? sometimes I don't want to use my mouse to do this little manipulation.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Found it thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49861033/what-is-the-shortcut-for-ctrl-click-in-visual-code) [duplicate question].
Go to Preferences with and look for the command `editor.action.openLink` and assign your preferred shortcut.

edit: perhaps, it works only with links and underlined "view" files for example, not with Classes.