# SCSS file not getting linked with the HTML file

Tags: html, css, sass

I was following a YouTube tutorial which taught me how to create a portfolio website. He said that he will do the styling using csss, as it offeres more advantages than css, for this project. I have installed all the extensions he used. I wrote the code, exactly same to his code, and then taught of changing it later according to  my needs. But, when I have finished the code, I was facing some issues with implementing the styles in the webpage. The style seems to not be linked correctly with the HTML webpage. This is the linking part present in the HTML code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Portfolio</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="templates/styles.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-1ycn6IcaQQ40/MKBW2W4Rhis/DbILU74C1vSrLJxCq57o941Ym01SwNsOMqvEBFlcgUa6xLiPY/NS5R+E6ztJQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;500;600;700;800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

The file format seems to be also correct to me, but I don`t understand where the problem is. I have tried to change the extension name from templates/styles.css to templates/styles/sccs, but nothing works. This is the image of my folder structure in VS code:
[File structure in VS Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3QrsR.png)

can somebody please help me find the issue. I have tried contacting the person who craeted this video in several ways, but he didn`t replied for the past week. Thank you.

Edit: I have tried everything, but it is not working. Here is my folder structure with my HTML code, please let me know if my linking process is correct or not. Thank you. [Folder structure with SASS files and HTML code with linking part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7JHcQ.png)

I have just connected the scss file with my html code, but the styling are not implemented inside the webpage. This is what I see once I run the HTML code in my server in VS Code. [Current webpage image without styling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMSxI.png)

Comment: You need to compile your SCSS down to CSS first. There are multiple VSCode extensions that can do this automatically as you type; e.g. [Live Sass Compiler](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=glenn2223.live-sass).

Comment: Yes I did that, then I clicked on Watch SASS, then i noticed 2 additional files were present, styles.css and styles.css.map. I tried linking both, but they didn't work. Do you know any other solutions, as this issue is really frustrating. Thank you for your answer so far.

Comment: Try changing `templates/styles.css` to `/styles.css`.

Comment: I did, still not working.

Comment: Could you give me a link to the tutorial so that I can try following it myself?

Comment: yeah sure, below is the link for the tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xV7S8BhIeBo&list=LL&index=13

Comment: He covers that part in the section called "Switch between sections".

Comment: I watched until the end, can't reproduce on my part. Press and hold Ctrl while clicking the underlined `styles/styles.css` part and see where it takes you to (see also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49861033)), then fix the directory accordingly.

Comment: Ok, I am going to check.

Comment: Just checked, I have received an error saying that the file does not exist. So I pressed the "create file" button and created a file named "styles.scss" and linked with it. Now when I control and click on that link, it shows me the correct scss file, but the styling is still not implemented in the webpage. I don`t understand why.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to get that `SCSS` to compile to `CSS`. Note that browsers are only able to parse CSS and not `SCSS`

After you build/compile you `SCSS` you can link to that compiled version.

How you compile depends on how you will be linking. Can look like this if your compiled `CSS` is under `dist` dir.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="dir/styles.css">
```

In your specific case it seems to be:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles/styles.css">
```

Comment: Nikola Mitic I did that, I installed Live SASS Compiler extension and clicked on Watch SASS, then, I saw 2 more css files, one called style.css and the other one called styles.css.map. I have tried to add both files name, but it still doesn't work. Can you tell me any other solutions, if possible, as this issue is a bit annoying. Thank you for your answer, so far.

Comment: Path seem to be wrong.

Comment: @DanishZubair I have updated the example. Tip, alway look at the browser network tab to see what's happening with your assets.